# How can i connect my instagram with selenium BOT?

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, safari, instagram

I hope you're right.

I write to the community cause i create a BOT with selenium to connect an instagram profil but i have a error on my code at the moment i where the connection of ursername and password. When the window of the instagram opening the username it's write properly but the password too at the same ligne for example : login : usernamepassword

I hope i can find someone can tell me what's it's wrong on my code and figure out with this :

```
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/") 
time.sleep(5)
username=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")
password=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']")

username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys("username")
time.sleep(3)
password.send_keys("password")
login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']").click()

THE ERROR MESSAGE THAT I HAVE : 

ElementNotInteractableException           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[49], line 23
     21 time.sleep(3)
     22 password.send_keys("password")
---> 23 login = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']").click()
     26 #driver.quit()

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:93, in WebElement.click(self)
     91 def click(self) -> None:
     92     """Clicks the element."""
---> 93     self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py:394, in WebElement._execute(self, command, params)
    392     params = {}
    393 params["id"] = self._id
--> 394 return self._parent.execute(command, params)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:344, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    342 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    343 if response:
--> 344     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    345     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    346     return response

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:229, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    227         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

Answer (score 0):

- `ElementNotInteractableException` is raised when an element is found, but it is not in a state that can be interacted with, such as being hidden or disabled and `button[type='submit']`, possibly that the login button is not currently interactable when you're trying to click it.
- Add a `wait` or `sleep` before locating and clicking the login button. This will ensure that the button is `visible and enabled` before attempting to interact with it.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Wait for the login button to be clickable
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']")))
login_button.click()
```

or you can also use `time.sleep()`

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']").click()
```